# I have getting __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object this error while sesiion create through jQuery-ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am create a `FinalResult` class

```
class FinalResult
{
    var $ReuestAnswer = null;
    var $givenAnswer  = null;
    var $questionScore = 0;

    function setScore()
    {

    }

    function getScore()
    {
        return $this->questionScore;
    }
}
```

and my function code is

```
$session  = JFactory::getSession();
$getFinalResult = $session->get('FinalResult');
//echo '<pre/>';
print_r($getFinalResult);

if(!empty($getFinalResult))
{
    $getScore = $session->get('score');
    $session->set('score',$getScore);
}
else
{
    $FinalResult = new FinalResult();
    $session->set('FinalResult',$FinalResult);
}
```

My question is that I'm trying to store data in session but getting this error:

`"__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object ( [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => FinalResult [ReuestAnswer] => [givenAnswer] => [questionScore] => 0 ) "`

and my values are not store in session.

How can I do this.

Comment: This usually means you have not loaded class definition before storing/retrieving data from session....

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are loading the session, before your autoloader is instantiated. Make sure that the FinalResult class is/can be loaded (either via an autoloader, or manually via a require_once call).